# Insert array of items to database one by one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have an array of items that I want to insert into the database one after another, something like this:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

so basically, there would be a for..of loop iterating over this array and inserting them one after the another.
I want to break out of the loop once an error happens, so for instance the error occurred after the 8th item:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}] 
                                 ^: error here
```

So I want to stop the execution at this phase, how to implement this?
my code looks like this:

```js
const [createOneUser, { isLoading, isError, isSuccess, error }] = useCreateOneUserMutation()
const bulkUsers = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}] 
const handleInsert = async()=>{
 for(const obj of bulkUsers){
    await createOneUser(obj) // <--- here
 }
}
return <button onClick={handleInsert}>start bulk insert</button>
```

this looks different from how we usually do the stuff using `useEffect`, but that's just a drafted plan to implement this. and I have no idea how to do this.

How to implement a similar logic in the redux toolkit query?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using the `.unwrap()` method of redux, *unwrapping* the mutation hook [0] given parameter returns a promise that you can await.

+ by default, if you have a loop of queries going into one end-point, redux will not execute the requests blindly quickly as the for loop loops, instead, it runs them one by one, therefore, if you have a logic similar to the one I had, you should `.unwrap()` then `await` your query to detect if it was failed or resolved.

```js
const [createOneUser, { isLoading, isError, isSuccess, error }] = useCreateOneUserMutation()
const bulkUsers = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}] 
const handleInsert = async()=>{
 for(const obj of bulkUsers){
    try{
        await (createOneUser(obj).unwrap()) // <--- here
    }
    catch(error){
        // ... handle error logic here
    }
 }
}
return <button onClick={handleInsert}>start bulk insert</button>
```

Important: [How to break out of an async for loop on button press in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73720229/how-to-break-out-of-an-async-for-loop-on-button-press-in-react)

Special thanks to (markerikson)

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/2697#discussioncomment-3646116